# Visual Stusio doesn't recognize System.Web.DataVisualization

Tags: c#, mschart, system.web

I'm writing a Windows Forms application in C# in Visual Studio.

I'm using the MSChart in my project.

I want to create an object:

```
public Series myseries = new Series("Default");
```

The VS doesn't recognize the class Series. As far as I understand, it would be recognized if I write

```
using System.Web.DataVisualization
```

If I add using System.Web.DataVisualization then the project doen't recognize DataVisualization . It says that DataVisualization doesn't exist in System.Web.

I looked at the list of references in the project. On the tab .NET I see a reference about System.Web.DataVisualization.dll . To be sure, I found this .dll and dragged it to the project - it didn't help.

I reinstalled MSChart component. No change. The DataVisualization is still not recognized in System.Web.

I've found in the Internet several suggestions how to solve this issue - nothing has helped.

Could you please direct me what may be the reason for DataVisualization being not recognized?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following line has helped: using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting